# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to read the page source of a web page by this code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15"

page = urlopen(url)

htmlSource = page.read().decode("utf-8")

f=open("output.txt",'w')
f.write(htmlSource)
```

but I get this erroe:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I dont know if this page is encoded with utf-8 or not.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note the recommendation at the top of the documentation:  The [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) package is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface.

Comment: The HTTP protocol has multiple places to specify the encoding, and they needn't agree with each other - some will take precedence over others. That's why most people use a higher level library like `requests` instead of `urlopen` to simplify this.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know if this page is encoded with utf-8 or not.

If you don't know how the page is encoded, you can just write the bytes to the file without trying to examine them:

```
page = urlopen(url)
htmlSource = page.read()
f=open("output.txt",'wb')
f.write(htmlSource)
```

Comment: I did that but there will be unknown characters in the output file.

Comment: Since this saves the page contents to a file exactly, then if the page has an unknown character then the file will have an unknown character. If you don't want to save the page to a file as is, what do you want to do instead?

Comment: Your question and code is about saving a page to file, so that's what this answer covers. If this is not what you want to do, then you should update your question to ask about what you *do* want to do.